# React-Native Constructor

Tags: react-native

Please help me find what is wrong in the following React-Native code?

It says after constructor (props) should have ';' semicolon. I don't know if I declared it in the right way.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  constructor (props){
    this.state = {
      text: 'HI'
    }
  }
  render () {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input}
      placeholder = 'Enter Value...'
      placeholderTextColor ='#E74292'
      onChangeText = {(text) => {
        this.setState({text})
      }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'#F4C724',

  },
  input :{
marginTop:30,
height:30,
width:30,
borderWidth:2,
padding:10,
borderRadius: 5,
borderColor:'#1287A5'
  }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the component as `class` instead of `function` if you want a constructor:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      text: 'HI'
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Enter Value..."
          placeholderTextColor="#E74292"
          onChangeText={text => {
            this.setState({ text });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F4C724'
  },
  input: {
    marginTop: 30,
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    borderWidth: 2,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: '#1287A5'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

constructor only works in class based component so switch to class based component rather than . functional whihc is now.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      text: 'HI'
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Enter Value..."
          placeholderTextColor="#E74292"
          onChangeText={text => {
            this.setState({ text });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F4C724'
  },
  input: {
    marginTop: 30,
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    borderWidth: 2,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: '#1287A5'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to study the difference between functional and class component.
Functional component is just a plain java-script function which also known as stateless component. They do not manage their own state or have access to the lifecycle methods. 
for more please follow the link below:

https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108

Answer (score 0):

you can use useState , the dynamic function value loads to the initial variable on load

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
export default function Home({navigation}){

   //function getversion onload 

    const [initval,setInitval] = useState(()=>{ return '123456'});

    return(
        <View  style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text> {initval} </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a constructor() in functional components. You should either change function component to class component or go and check out the react doc about [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). You are going to have a better understanding of the differences between react class components and react functional components.